# Pros and cons of the below data model

Tags: database-design

[image: Data Model]

[image: Table Structure]

For the given data model and table structure, Can you please let me know the pros and cons of this design.
I was asked the same question with the same info in an interview so i didn't know where to start looking for the answers. Are there any best practices one should look for, or is there something really wrong with the data model asked in the question.?

Comment: A data model is not good nor bad. It can be a good match of a certain *scenario*, with a certain set of *requirements* and *business rules*. In order to be able to help you, more context is needed: What is this data model supposed to *represent*? What do you want to use it for? Which kind of *operations* do you intend to perform with it? Which kind of *queries* do you want to be able to respond with it?

Comment: I was asked the same question with the same info in an interview so i didn't know where to start looking for the answers. Are there any best practices one should look for, or is there something really wrong with the data model asked in the question.?

Comment: Add your comment to the problem statement... it gives *some* (very minor) extra context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further data, a few commments on things I would call *unusual* or *suspicious* about this schema:

1. **Relationships (foreign keys)**: The symbols indicating which column relates to each column are not properly drawn, or do not follow any "common" standard. In good logic, the `documentId` column from the `File_tbl` should point to the `documentId` PK of `Document_tbl`. And so on. The symbols used to draw the relationships are not known to me; the "usual" ones are normally either ["Crow foot"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878359/Data-modelling-using-ERD-with-Crow-Foot-Notation) and ["Chen notation"](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/chen-erd-notation), but also ["UML"](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/uml-notation), ["Barker's"](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/barkers-erd-notation) and ["IDEF1X"](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/idef1x-notation). I don't know whether this is another standard, or a drawing tool not being properly used.
2. **EAV Pattern**: This usage of an attribute table is called an ["Entity Attribute Value Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). This pattern has been severly criticised by many. It gives lots of flexibility on having the possibility of *infinite* and *not-known-ahead* attributes for a certain entity. However, it has got some heavy limitations. Among them, the lack of ability to make databases check that the *type* of the data is the right one (the values are normally represented as text). In an scenario with just three types of attributes, it should seem sensible to just have three columns `fillingDate`, `formType` and `formCompany` on the `Attribute_tbl`, and *not* have either the `Attribute_tbl` nor the `AttributeType_tbl`.
3. **Probably wrong data**: Because of the EAV; you have one document (represented by id 6) that is *both* 'Marketing Materials' and 'Spec Sheet'. This doesn't make sense to me (but, without knowing the business rules of this scenario, this is just my *gut's guess*); and would consider it a design flaw. This is possible because of the nature of the EAV model, and because there is no restriction on `(documentId, documentTypeId)` being `UNIQUE` on table `Attribute_tbl`.